# Passing a Enum value as a parameter from JSF

Tags: java, jsf, enums, el

I am trying to migrate my existing code to using Enum and I run into some problems due to my lack experience with Enum. First of all here is my structures. In my `EJB`, alongs with Entity, I have a enum class (not sure if it even a class).

```
public enum Type {
    PROFILE_COMMENT,
    GROUP_COMMENT
}
```

At my managed bean `myBean.java`, I have

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class myBean {

    private Type type;

    public myBean() {
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void Test(Type t){
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}
```

then at my JSF,

```
<h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{myBean.Test(myBean.type.PROFILE_COMMENT)}" />
```

I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` saying `Type` is not a class

The reason I have `Type` in my EJB so that I can create an enumerated type for my Entity, so my query would look like this

```
select c from X c where c.type = Type.PROFILE_COMMENT
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't access enums like that in EL. JSF has however builtin enum converters for EL. You can just use the enum name as string.

```
<h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{myBean.Test('PROFILE_COMMENT')}" />
```

Comment: @BalusC: Although this worked for me while using glassfish but after migrating to tomcat 7 this failed, could you point out why ?

Comment: here is the link to details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534130/passing-a-enum-value-as-a-parameter-from-jsf-failed-after-migrating-to-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

In my case [that](http://java.paykin.info/enums-in-jsf/) helped me.

Simple compare enum to its value. EL recognize it and also check if that value exists while validating xhtml.

```
<c:if test="#{requestManager.selectedRequestType == 'ItemCreate' or requestManager.selectedRequestType == 'ItemChange'}"></c:if>
```