# Passing a Enum value as a parameter from JSF (revisited)

Tags: java, jsf, enums, scope, el

[Passing a Enum value as a parameter from JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916871/passing-a-enum-value-as-a-parameter-from-jsf)

This question already deals with this issue, however the proposed solution has not worked for me. I define the following enumeration in my backing bean:

```
public enum QueryScope {
  SUBMITTED("Submitted by me"), ASSIGNED("Assigned to me"), ALL("All items");

  private final String description;

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  QueryScope(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

Then I use it as a method parameter

```
public void test(QueryScope scope) {
  // do something
}
```

And use it via EL in my JSF page

```
<h:commandButton
      id        = "commandButton_test"
      value     = "Testing enumerations"
      action    = "#{backingBean.test('SUBMITTED')}" />
```

So far so good - identical to the problem posed in the original question. However I have to deal with a `javax.servlet.ServletException: Method not found: %fully_qualified_package_name%.BackingBean.test(java.lang.String)`.

So it seems that JSF is interpreting the method call as if I would like to call a method with String as parameter type (which of course does not exist) - therefore no implicit conversion takes place.

What could be the factor that makes the behavior differ in this example from the aforelinked?

Comment: does the backingbean has an instance of QueryScope? cant see your entire backingbean class but i could imagine that would be a reason jsf isnt registering the enum

Comment: The `enum` definition is part of the `BackingBean` class. It itself has no instance of `QueryScope` as a member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `backingBean`, you may have written a method with the `enum` parameter:

```
<!-- This won't work, EL doesn't support Enum: -->
<h:commandButton ... action="#{backingBean.test(QueryScope.SUBMITTED)}" />

// backingBean:
public void test(QueryScope queryScope) {
    // your impl
}
```

But, the `proposed solution` does not use enum, it uses `String`. That's because EL doesn't support enum at all:

```
<!-- This will work, EL does support String: -->
<h:commandButton ... action="#{backingBean.test('SUBMITTED')}" />    

// backingBean:
public void test(String queryScopeString) {
    QueryScope queryScope = QueryScope.valueOf(queryScopeString);
    // your impl
}
```