# Access value from a Map where Key is Enum Type in JSF Facelets

Tags: jsf, enums

I have a Map defined in my controller as follows

```
Map<AddressTypeEnum,Address> addressMap = new HasMap<AddressTypeEnum,Address>();
```

where AddressTypeEnum is a Enum type with values as HOME,WORK

in facelets, I was trying to access the field of Address as follows

```
<p:inputText value="#{controller.addressMap['HOME'].addressLine1}"/>
```

It gives me error target not reachable as null. Is there any thing wrong with my facelets code

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to have such complex EL expressions. Put the expression into a method in the controller - then you also no longer have the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue as follows.. May be useful to others

I used Ominifaces from BaluC

In the facelets page, I added the follwing line

```
 <o:importConstants type="com.eplm.chits.entities.common.AddressTypeEnum" var="addressType"/>
```

Then I used

```
<p:inputText id="homeId" value="#{chitUserController.address[addressType.HOME].addressLine1}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

EL doesn't have built-in functionality to work with Enums. You can only test if Enum-typed variable holds some value like in: `rendered="#{enumVar=='HOME'}"`, because in this case implicit call to enumVar.toString() is executed.

Probably, using Enum as the key for your Map, you want to enforce compile-time checking of your keys. You could use `Map<String, Address>` and `addressMap.put(AddressTypeEnum.HOME.toString(), someAddress)` instead.

From facelets template you then access `addressMap` either with

`#{controller.addressMap['HOME'].addressLine1}`

or with

`#{controller.addressMap.HOME.addressLine1}`.

Another solution would be to introduce controller method, as @sleske advises, which takes String parameter, gets Enum instance for this String and gets the value from the map:

```
Map<AddressTypeEnum, Address> addressMap;
...
public Address getAddress(String type) {
    AddressTypeEnum addressType = AddressTypeEnum.valueOf(type);
    return addressMap.get(addressType);
}
```

...and use it with `#{controller.getAddress('HOME').addressLine1}`

UPD: There is three-years-old StackOverflow question on the same problem: [Passing a Enum value as a parameter from JSF (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489676/passing-a-enum-value-as-a-parameter-from-jsf-revisited)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Primefaces, it is possible to use the `<p:importEnum />` tag, as described in: [Primefaces's showcase](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/misc/importEnum.xhtml?jfwid=072cb):

```
<p:importEnum type="javax.faces.application.ProjectStage"
              var="JsfProjectStages"
              allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES"/>
<h:outputText value="#{JsfPRojectStages.Key}" />
```