# Passing enum value as parameter to bean method from JSF pages fail after migrating to tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, el, converters

I recently migrated my JSF app(using primefaces) from glassfish 3.1 to tomcat7 server. Previously passing the enum value as string to managed bean methods through `actionlistener`  attribute worked(without the need for a converter to convert string to enum) but now it fails with  `javax.el.MethodNotFoundException`.

JSF page:

> ```
> <h:form>
>    <h:outputLabel value="Title"/><br/>
>    <p:inputText value="#{lobController.current.title}"/>
>
>    <p:commandButton action="#{lobController.create('CAR')}" value="Post"/>
> </h:form>
> ```

Mangaged bean method

> ```
> public void create(Type type) {
>   ...
> }
> ```

Log messages:

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /_newLOB.xhtml @85,111
>   action="#{lobController.create('CAR')}": Method not found:
>   d432.xontrollers.LOBController@15b2cec.create(java.lang.String)   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:110)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

---

### Edit

This starts working if I change the managed bean method as follow:

> ```
> public void create(String type) {
>      Type type = Type.valueOf(type);
>      ...
> }
> ```

---

**Using Primefaces 3.1 with JSF 2.1.6 on Tomcat 7.0.14**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bug in Tomcat's EL implementation. I've reported it for you: [issue 52970](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52970). Hopefully they aren't as picky on this as on my previous reports.

Until they get it fixed, your best bet is to drop a copy of [Glassfish 3's EL 2.2 implementation JAR file](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/glassfish/web/el-impl/2.2/el-impl-2.2.jar) in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and tell Mojarra to use it instead by the following entry in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

---

**Update**: the ticket mentions that it's fixed and it will be in 7.0.27 and onwards.