# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException when passing enum value as method parameter (JBoss 7.1.1)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, jboss7.x

The following JSF view snippets:

```
<h:commandLink value="Search" action="#{personSearch.search('SEARCH_TERM')}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" />

<h:commandLink value="Search" action="#{personSearch.search('SPECIALITY_CODE')}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

Calls the following bean method:

```
public void search(SearchType searchType) {
    ...
```

Which takes the following enum type as a parameter:

> public enum SearchType {  SEARCH_TERM, SPECIALITY_CODE  }

Is failing with a MethodNotFoundException:

```
10:34:06,851 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/core-webapp].[FacesServlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /person/search.xhtml @59,39 action="#{personSearch.search('SPECIALITY_CODE')}": Method not found: Proxy for view class: net.hl.core.view.PersonSearch of EJB: PersonSearch.search(java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
```

I'm using **JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final with Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1**.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Its an `EL` lib problem. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534130/passing-enum-value-as-parameter-to-bean-method-from-jsf-pages-fail-after-migrati

Comment: That question references Tomcat 7 - is it the same issue in JBoss 7.1.1?

Comment: JBoss EL is far better than Tomcat's.

Comment: This exception suggests that the method is in an EJB instead of a normal managed bean for some reason. I've never bound the view to the enterprise bean directly so I can't tell from experience if this is expected or not, but I'd try binding to a normal managed bean first.

Comment: I've switched it to a ManagedBean and still get the error: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /person/search.xhtml @59,39 action="#{personSearch.search('SPECIALITY_CODE')}": Method not found: net.hl.core.view.PersonSearch@301b66.search(java.lang.String)