# How to access object methods using dataTable in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, last.fm

I'm working with LastFM api, let's say I have a class called `Artist` which I call in this `dataTable`:

```
<h:dataTable var="artist" value="#{personEAO.topArtists}" >
    <h:column>Artist : #{artist.name} </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Artit have a field which refers to his picture :

```
artist.getImageURL(ImageSize.LARGE)
```

Which works fine, but how do I call this method in my jsf page using dataTable ?

Comment: Check this question out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916871/passing-a-enum-value-as-a-parameter-from-jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched around for Javadocs, but I couldn't find them anywhere. The answer depends on what kind of constant `ImageSize.LARGE` is.

If `ImageSize` is an enum, just do:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{artist.getImageURL('LARGE')}" />
```

But if it isn't and is thus a `public static` constant, then one of the ways is to wrap it in some helper bean which returns exactly that:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{artist.getImageURL(someHelperBean.ImageSize_LARGE)}" />
```

I of course assume that your environment supports EL 2.2.