# Compare enums jstl el

Tags: java, enums, jstl, el

```
 <c:forEach items="${availableBadges}" var="badge">
 <div>
 <c:choose>
 <c:when test="${badge} == ${user.activeBadge};">
```

badge is enum with two string fields.

User has correct getter and returns an instance of Badge. The foreach is working correctly, But I can not get the synatx right for comparing enums ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your EL syntax is invalid. The `==` operator must be in the same `${}` scope as the both operands and there should be no trailing semicolon.

```html
<c:when test="${badge == user.activeBadge}">
```

This has nothing to do with enums. The same syntax should be used for all other types.

#### See also:

- [How to testing for enum equality in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524420/how-to-testing-for-enum-equality-in-jsf/2524901#2524901)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [questions tagged `[enums]`+`[el]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enums+el)