# Show form when item on selectOneMenu is selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on j2ee web application (jsf2 and primefaces) and i wonder how to display form depending on the item selected from select one menu.
I tried this but it didn't work.

```
<h:form id="global">
   <p:panel  header="Association">
         ...
     <p:outputLabel  value="Travel Class" />     
     <p:selectOneMenu id="associationType" style="width: 230px" value="#{associationMBean.travelClass}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" itemValue="" />  
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seminar" itemValue="Seminar" />   
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Honeymoon" itemValue="Honeymoon" /> 
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Organized Trip" itemValue="Organized Trip" />
                                            <p:ajax update=":hidePanel"/> 
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>     
   </p:panel>
</h:form>
<p:panel id="hidePanel" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; border: 0;display: none " header="Remarks (Optional)"  rendered="#{associationMBean.travelClass eq Seminar}"> 
<h:form>            
<p:inputTextarea style="width: 100% ; height: 100px" value="#{associationMBean.description}" ></p:inputTextarea> 
</h:form>              
</p:panel>
```

**Update**

```
<html 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Visa Application-Thailand</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div align="center">
            <div>
                <img class="logo" src="images/banner.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <p:panel style="width: 61%;  border-color: indianred; border-width: 2px; margin-top: 10px"> 
                <h:form id="global">
                    <p:panel style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 14px ; border: 0" header="Association">
                        <table border="0" >
                            <tbody > 
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel  value="Association Type" />
                                    </td >
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectmenu" style="width: 230px" value="#{associationMBean.type}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Class" itemValue="" />  
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seminar" itemValue="Seminar" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Organized Trip" itemValue="Organized Trip" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Honeymoon" itemValue="Honeymoon" />
                                            <p:ajax update=":hidePanel"/>
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>   

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Date of Departure" for="departure" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:calendar  value="#{associationMBean.departure}" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yy" style="width: 250px" id="departure"></p:calendar>
                                        <p:watermark value="01/01/2014" for="departure"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Date of Arrival" for="arrival" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:calendar  value="#{associationMBean.arrival}" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yy" style="width: 250px" id="arrival"></p:calendar>
                                        <p:watermark value="01/01/2014" for="arrival"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel  value="Travel Agency " for="travelAgency"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:inputText id="travelAgency" value="#{associationMBean.travelAgency}" style="width: 220px"></p:inputText>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel  value="Airline " for="airline"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:inputText id="airline" value="#{associationMBean.airline}" style="width: 220px"></p:inputText>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel  value="Travel Class" />
                                    </td >
                                    <td align="left">        
                                        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectclass" style="width: 230px" value="#{associationMBean.travelClass}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Class" itemValue="" />  
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{associationMBean.allClasses}" />
                                            <!--  <p:ajax update=":hidePanel"/> !-->
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>                                   
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 

                                <tr >
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <p:outputLabel  value="Hotels " for="hotels" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <p:inputTextarea id="hotels" value="#{associationMBean.hotels}" style="width: 220px"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </p:panel>
                    <div align="right" style="margin-top: 20px ">
                        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" style="font-size: 14px;"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save"  ajax="false" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" style="font-size: 14px;" action="#{associationMBean.addAssociation()}" />
                    </div>
                </h:form>            
                <p:panel id="hidePanel" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; border: 0;display: none " header="Remarks (Optional)" >
                    <h:form rendered="#{associationMBean.type == 'Seminar'}" >
                        <p:inputTextarea style="width: 100% ; height: 100px" value="#{visaMBean.description}" ></p:inputTextarea>
                    </h:form>
                </p:panel>         
            </p:panel>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

the code above is the whole html code after adding some updates  `<h:form rendered="#{associationMBean.type == 'Seminar'}" >` But still can't display the hidePane when i select Seminar from the selectOneMenu.
Have you any idea what am i missing??

Comment: Try to surround hidePanel with a outputPanel and update this outputPanel.

Comment: Same issue when i select Seminar nothing shows up

Comment: Leo Zhao advice is the solution, the reason is that the panel is not present the html page, because the rendered attribute is evaluated to false, ajax request can update only dom elements which are present in the html page.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<p:panel id="hidePanel" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 14px; border: 0;display: none " header="Remarks (Optional)"> 
  <h:form rendered="#{associationMBean.travelClass eq 'Seminar'}">
    <p:inputTextarea style="width: 100% ; height: 100px" value="#{associationMBean.description}" ></p:inputTextarea> 
  </h:form>              
</p:panel>
```

You can not update components which are not in the DOM and when a component is not rendered it is not in there. So you need to update the parent of the conditionally rendered component.
And as `#{associationMBean.travelClass}` is a String you need to wrap `'Seminar'` with single quotes `'`.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524420/how-to-testing-for-enum-equality-in-jsf